# Extend tx_news with 1 field without extension_builder

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, tx-news

I try to extend the tx_news extension with the field `imageright`.

For that I found this tutorial: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/2.2.1/Main/Tutorial/ExtendingNews/Index.html

The first step is to use extension_builder to add the field. As I already have a extension in where I want to implement the extension I do not want to use the extension_builder (also I tried it with a new extension and extend the news-model did not work - I have no clue how to do it right). However this are the steps I did:

- In my extension `my_template` I added the folders and file: `Classes/Domain/Model/News.php`:

  ```
      class MyTemplate_Domain_Model_News extends Tx_News_Domain_Model_News {

              /**
              * @var bool
              */
              protected $imageright;


              /**
               * Returns the imageright
               *
               * @return bool $imageright
               */
              public function getImageright() {
                      return $this->imageright;
              }


              /**
               * Sets the sort
               *
               * @param bool $imageright
               * @return void
               */
              public function setImageright($imageright)
              {
                  $this->imageright = $imageright;
              }

      }

  ?>
  ```
- /Ressources/Private/extend-news.txt:

  ```
  Domain/Model/News
  ```
- Created the field imageright as tinyint in the table `tx_news_domain_model_news` (and added it to the SQL file)
- I knew I have to create a TCA file in `/Configuration/TCA/`, but I have no clue how this should look like or what name it needs to have. I think this is the last step I need to make this working.

Also note the extension `my_template` was just a template, so before my changes there where no Classes and no TCA files.

Answer (score 2):

Solution is to use this tutorial: http://www.lukasjakob.com/extend-a-typo3-extbase-model-with-custom-field/

Comment: I have used this solution but the new field is not showing in frontend, debug newsItem , don't show it also, but i see it is the in the DB. Do you have an idea ?