# Tx_news extend with new fields

Tags: typo3, tx-news, typo3-10.x

I like to extend my news extension with new fields, like two urls that can be entered from backend.
Is there a link or hint how to do that ?

I'm using Typo3 v10 and extension_builder can't be installed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extend tx\_news with 1 field without extension\_builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43094622/extend-tx-news-with-1-field-without-extension-builder)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you check the documentation of EXT:news? There is a [chapter](https://docs.typo3.org/p/georgringer/news/8.5/en-us/DeveloperManual/ExtendNews/ProxyClassGenerator/Index.html) exactly for this topic. Furthermore you can check [EXT:eventnews](https://github.com/georgringer/eventnews), which is also mentioned in the documentation to see how it works.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that the extension_builder can't be installed on the Typo3 v10

Comment: You don't need EXT:extension_builder! Just read the documentation and build the code yourself. Let you inspire by EXT:eventnews. EXT:extension_builder just produces way too much overhead that is unnecessary.

Comment: Yes this is a good hint, i have read this and implemetend the new link, now the new field show in backend an is stored in the DB, but when it comes to frontend, nothing show, when i debug with debug>{news.item} the new field is not in the list. Do you have an idea why this happen ? Thanks!

Comment: Did you [create the domain model and register it](https://docs.typo3.org/p/georgringer/news/8.5/en-us/DeveloperManual/ExtendNews/ProxyClassGenerator/Index.html#register-the-class)?

Comment: I have missed to add this line : 
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXT']['news']['classes']['Domain/Model/NewsDefault'][] = 'my_tmpl';

Now the field is showing when i debug the object "newsItem", but is empty, in the DB it contains some chars, i think i did something wrong

Comment: Thanks, my issue was due that the field in DB wasn't the same label with the one in the class, also  config {   tx_extbase {     persistence { don't work for mapping so i use 
plugin.tx_news {
    persistence {
        classes {
            GeorgRinger\News\Domain\Model\News {
                subclasses {